# Automated OCR program or off-the-shelf tool to scan PDFs/images and output into excel documents

Tags: python, automation, ocr

I'm new to programming and recently started getting into Python a lot more seriously. However, I've done some projects that required programming in my company, so I have some background on how it works (or how to scour the internet! lol). 
Recently however, we have had a client that sends us invoices in PDF formats and we would like to automate all the invoices to compile into one .csv file.

I've been picking up a few OCR codes (I ran my first image-to-text output recently), however I don't think I'm 100% capable of creating such automation yet since I'm still very fresh in programming. It would require at least a few weeks, and I'm not sure if it's worth it if we could just ask the client to set up a more accurate excel spreadsheet to send over every time.

That's why I'm turning to an already available OCR tool. I recently found this gem: https://www.pdftoexcel.com/  however it is a very manual process and not as automated as we could like. If there is a way to program a script to upload an available PDF file from a certain folder in order to upload it to the website and export it into an Excel file every time we receive an invoice, would it be possible to share?

It would also be a big plus if there would be a way to upload a batch of invoices and identify different charges, providing a summary across the scanned invoices, particularly in the categories

I hope what I'm asking for makes sense. Let me know if you'd require more clarification.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of stuff available for Python, if you have a quick search on Google or StackOverflow. I believe I used Tesseract OCR in the past.

My experience is that you will get serviceable OCR with some of the popular Python libraries, but the excellent stuff will come with a price tag.

Try some tests with your PDF invoices, but if you are getting even slightly questionable results, you may have to consider more expensive alternatives (or even standalone machinery!).

If the client is sending you clear, nicely formatted PDFs with a good font, I don't see why free Python libraries wouldn't be sufficient.